# Corollary (1.2.6) from EGA 1 (2nd edition)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ and $A'$ be two commutative rings with unity, and let $\phi: A' \to A$ be a ring homomorphism. We can then define the map $^a\phi:$ Spec$(A) \to$ Spec$(A')$ by $^a \phi(\mathfrak{p}) = \phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}).$ The statement of Corollary 1.2.6 says the following:

> For $^a\phi($Spec$(A))$ to be dense in Spec$(A')$, it is necessary and sufficient that each element of the kernel of $\phi$ be nilpotent.

I think a more accurate statement should be that the kernel of $\phi$ is equal to $\{0\}$ instead of every element of Ker$\phi$ being nilpotent. Here's my reasoning:
$$^a\phi(\text{Spec}(A)) \ \text{is dense in Spec}(A')$$
$$\iff \overline{^a\phi(\text{Spec}(A))} = \text{Spec}(A')$$
$$\iff \overline{^a\phi(V(\{0\}))} = \text{Spec}(A')$$
$$\iff V(\phi^{-1}(\{0\})) = \text{Spec(A')}$$
$$\iff \text{ker}(\phi) = 0$$

I'm assuming that there's a mistake somewhere in here. I would appreciate it if anyone could point out what I did wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is correct that $^a\Phi(\text{Spec}(A))$ is dense in $\text{Spec}(A')$ if and only if $V(\ker \Phi) =V(\Phi^{-1}(\{0\})) = \text{Spec}(A')$. The last "$\iff$" is not true.

Generally it holds for ideals $I,J \subseteq A'$: $V(I)\subseteq V(J) \iff \sqrt{J}\subseteq \sqrt{I}$. For
$$ V(I) \subseteq V(J) \iff \forall p\subseteq A', p \text{ prime ideal}, p \supseteq I: p \supseteq J \iff J \subseteq \bigcap_{p \supseteq I} p = \sqrt{I}$$
This means
$$V(\ker \Phi) = \text{Spec}(A') = V(\{0\}) \iff \sqrt{\ker \Phi} = \sqrt{0} \iff \ker \Phi \subseteq \sqrt{0},$$
which is equivalent to each element of $\ker \Phi$ is nilpotent.